# How to find technical details of a server using C++ from a URL

Tags: c++, web, server

I want to make a program that takes a URL as a variable from the user and my program actually read the technical details of the server such as type designation and the serial number for example I enter a URL("any URL") my program should display the servers name such as HP ProLiant 3800 and serial number . Is this possible using C plus plus .If it is possible then which things should I learn to do it. Thank you for helping .

Comment: What you're asking has nothing to do with C++ beyond your language of preference to accomplish this. The base question is the important one, how to query an http site for service properties. There are some basic properties many servers expose, others not so much. You may find browserspy.dk an interesting adventure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, these server specifics are just not publicly available, unless the servers are hosted by you and you can actually login to return the data you want.
I mean you can of course get general info such as hosting company, ISP, address etc but not more specific server details.

You could then use an API endpoint to get the general server details if that's what you want:
https://www.domaintools.com/resources/api-documentation/whois-lookup

But how to do than do that in C++ I do not know, sorry

Comment: Thank you for your reply .But can you suggest a particular programming language for this task.

Comment: Yes I can but I think that is more my personal opinion / experience then :)
I am a Software Engineer and code mainly in PHP using the Laravel Framework.
So with PHP I would just hit that API endpoint, give it the domain name and return that basic info. Probably make a little web interface for it too, depending on your situation and if you need scripts to run periodically you can do that too.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you find my answer at least a little bit useful? Please mark it, if not that's fine too of course :D